# Using ip address in ftp_connect

Tags: php, ftp, ip-address

I am trying to connect to a server which doesn't have any domain name like 'abc.com'. Rather I have to access it through its IP address.
I tried using ftp here, but the ftp_connect() doesn't support IP address.
Following is the code that I have tried..

```
<?php 
echo $ftp_server="182.8.87.89"; 
$ftp_user_name=""; 
$ftp_user_pass=""; 
$file = "new.txt";//tobe uploaded 
$remote_file = "test/heelo.txt"; 

// set up basic connection

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 
//echo 21;
// login with username and password 
echo $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass) or die(); 

// upload a file 
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) { 
echo "successfully uploaded $file\n"; 
exit; 
} else { 
echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n"; 
exit; 
} 
// close the connection 
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

The error that I get is`Warning: ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in      C:\xampp\htdocs\te\seperateupload.php on line 26`.

Comment: it'd be **VERY** weird if it didn't accept IPs, since that hostname **HAS** to be converted to an IP anyways.

Comment: I did a little google search and someone mentioned using the ip with `gethostbyaddr` then use what it produced with your `ftp_connect`

Comment: Yeah... But it does not!! :(

Comment: I tried it.. it changes the ip address as `static-182.8.87.89.ctrls.in`. And it says that no such host is known.